# Why reserve memory in the structure?

Tags: c++, c

I often see structures in the code, at the end of which there is a memory reserve.

```
struct STAT_10K4
{
     int32_t npos; // position number
     ...
     float Plts;
             Pxts;
     float Plto [NUM];
     uint32_t reserv [(NUM * 3)% 2 + 1];
};
```

1. Why do they do this?
2. Why are some of the reserve values dependent on constants?
3. What can happen if you do not make such reserves? Or make a mistake in their size?

Comment: probably something to avoid that someone writes Plto out of bounds, ... or something to allocate memory just in case more is needed in the application

Comment: perhaps its a attempt to optimize the size of the struct by adding padding, something you typically better leave to the compiler. Who is "they" ? In what code did you see it?

Comment: Impossible to tell without context. By the way, `(NUM * 3)% 2` is equal to just `NUM % 2`, so this calculation doesn't make much sense.

Comment: One application might be to avoid _false sharing_ when multiple threads access different elements in an array. However, this should be better solved by a prescription of suitable alignment requirements.

Comment: This is old project for old 86x debian

Comment: Just bad code, that's it?

Comment: In this case it seems to be to make the structure a multiple of 8 bytes long. Why should it be a multiple of 8 bytes? Don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would typically be to support variable-length records.  A couple of ways this could be used will be:

1 If the maximum number of records is known then a simple structure definition can accomodate all cases.

2 In many protocols there is a "header-data" idiom.  The header will be a fixed size but the data variable.  The data will be received as a "blob".  Thus the structure of the header can be declared and accessed by a pointer to the blob, and the data will follow on from that.  For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t messageId;
    uint32_t dataType;
    uint32_t dataLenBytes;
    uint8_t data[MAX_PAYLOAD];
}
tsMessageFormat;
```

The data is received in a blob, so a `void* ptr, size_t len`.

The buffer pointer is then cast so the message can be read as follows:

```
tsMessageFormat* pMessage = (psMessageFormat*) ptr;
for (int i = 0;  i < pMessage->dataLenBytes;  i++)
{
    //do something with pMessage->data[i];
}
```

In some languages the "data" could be specified as being an empty record, but C++ does not allow this.  Sometimes you will see the "data" omitted and you have to perform pointer arithmetic to access the data.

The alternative to this would be to use a builder pattern and/or streams.

Windows uses this pattern a lot; many structures have a `cbSize` field which allows additional data to be conveyed beyond the structure.  The structure accomodates most cases, but having cbSize allows additional data to be provided if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

This is a form of manual padding of a class to make its size a multiple of some number. In your case:

```
uint32_t reserv [(NUM * 3)% 2 + 1];
```

`NUM * 3 % 2` is actually nonsensical, as it would be equivalent to `NUM % 2` (not considering overflow). So if the array size is odd, we pad the `struct` with one additional `uint32_t`, on top of `+ 1` additional ones. This padding means that `STAT_10K4`'s size is always a multiple of 8 bytes.

You will have to consult the documentation of your software to see why exactly this is done. Perhaps padding this struct with up to 8 bytes makes some algorithm easier to implement. Or maybe it has some perceived performance benefit. But this is pure speculation.

Typically, the compiler will pad your `struct`s to 64-bit boundaries if you use any 64-bit types, so you don't need to do this manually.

---

*Note: This answer is specific to mainstream compilers and x86. Obviously this does not apply to compiling for TI-calculators with 20-bit `char` & co.*